# Kronecker product: Is it possible to simplify this product $e^{-A} \otimes e^{A}$ where $A$ is an invertible and symmetric matrix

Tags: reference-request, matrices, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

Let $A$ be an invertible, symmetric and tridiagonal matrix of size $n \times n$. Assume that $A_{i,i}=a \neq 0$ for $i=1\dotsc n$ and all the elements in the sub- and super-diagonal of $A$ are $b \neq 0$. I would like to simplify the following Kronecker product: $e^{-A} \otimes e^{A}$.

I know that, given the Kronecker sum [property](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixExponential.html) of matrix exponential ($e^{A\oplus B}= e^{A}\otimes e^{B}$), the following holds:

\begin{equation}
e^{-A} \otimes e^{A} = e^{-A \otimes I_n +I_n \otimes A}.
\end{equation}

Since $A \otimes I_n$ and $I_n \otimes A$ commutes, using [Zassenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#:%7E:text=Zassenhaus%20formula,-A%20related%20combinatoric&text=where%20the%20exponents%20of%20higher,of%20the%20above%20BCH%20expansion.) formula,

\begin{equation}
e^{-A} \otimes e^{A} = e^{-A \otimes I_n} e^{I_n \otimes A}=(e^{-A}\otimes I_n)(I_n \otimes e^{A})
\end{equation}

Given the above mentioned properties of matrix $A$, I was wondering whether it would be possible to further simplify this expression.

Comment: What does $e^A$ mean?  Is there a missing hypothesis about where the entries of $A$ come from?

Comment: It is the matrix exponential as defined in the provided link. I am not sure what you mean be the second part of your question. The enteries can be any non zero real numbers.

Comment: The formula you obtained can also be proved more quickly using $(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D) = (AC)\otimes (BD)$.

Comment: Agree on the first comment. I just showed a different variation of it.

Comment: Yes, I meant tridiagonal. Thanks. Just editted.

Comment: There is a sign error in your exponents, right?

Comment: Thank you both. It is now corrected. The error actually was propagated from the first equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can diagonalize your $A = VDV^{-1}$ explicitly; the closed formulas are [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal-Toeplitz-Matrix) for instance.

Once you have those matrices, you can write the orthogonal eigendecomposition
$$
\exp(-A) \otimes \exp(A) = (V\otimes V) \,\, (\exp(-D)\otimes \exp(D)) \, \,(V\otimes V)^{-1}.
$$
The diagonal matrix $\exp(-D)\otimes \exp(D)$ has elements $\exp(-\lambda_i + \lambda_j)$, $i,j=1,\dots,n$; when you replace it with the formulas for the eigenvalues, the $a$'s simplify out and you get a difference of two cosines that you can further manipulate using the sum-to-product formulas. I don't think it gets any simpler than that.

Alternatively, you can write $A = aI + bZ$, where $Z$ is the matrix with ones on the super- and subdiagonal, and write $\exp(A) = e^a \exp(bZ)$ (since the two summands commute) and
$$
\exp(-A) \otimes \exp(A) = \exp(-bZ) \otimes \exp(bZ).
$$
This shows in a simpler way that $a$ simplifies out from your expression.

Comment: +1 Fair enough. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Federico: Is it possible to find an explicit form for $exp(Z)$? where Z is the sum of two nilpotent matrices one upper and one lower triangular matrices.

Comment: @Mirar Yes, with the techniques described in the first half of the answer; just set $a=0$ (which is not restrictive since the answer does not depend on $A$ anyway).